Traer la informacion de un procedimiento almacenado en Spring boot
Estoy intentando traer la informacion de un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL pero me muestra el siguiente error:

Cannot invoke "com.application.rest.repository.SP_InventoryRepository.invProduct(java.lang.Long)" because "this.SP_Inventory" is null

El codigo que uso en la persistencia es el siguiente:
public interface SP_InventoryRepository extends CrudRepository<SP_Inventory, Long> {
     @Query(value="{CALL SP_InvProduct(:idStr)}",nativeQuery = true)
     List<SP_Inventory> invProduct(@Param("idStr") Long idStr);
}

Servicio
public interface ISP_InventoryService {
    List<SP_Inventory> invProduct(Long id);                                            
}

implementacion del servicio
 @Autowired
 private ISP_InventoryDAO SP_inventoryDAO;
    
 @Override
 public List<SP_Inventory> invProduct(Long id) {
     return SP_inventoryDAO.listInventory(id);        
 }

Cree esta entidad para que resiva la informacion del procedimiento almacenado:
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity

public class SP_Inventory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long idpro;
    private Long idstr;
    private String name;
    private String namepro;
    private Long cant;
    private String recived;
    private String detail;   
}

el sql del procedimiento almacenado es el siguiente:
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_InvProduct`(in store int)
BEGIN
select A.id, B.id idpro, C.id idstr, C.name, B.namePro, A.cant, A.recived, A.detail 
    from db_spring.inventory A
    left join db_spring.producto B on A.idProduct = B.id
    left join db_spring.store C on A.idstore = C.id
    where C.id = store;
END


Buenas, Oscar, no aparece reflejada la relación entre el DAO y el Repository en el código que has añadido a la pregunta. Ni tampoco se ve donde se está intentando hacer this.SP_Inventory.

No estoy seguro, pero intuyo que puede deberse a como escribiste la entidad SP_Inventory. Esto porque pareciera que spring está señalando que hay una variable dentro de una instancia que no se especifica que tiene el nombre de la entidad y es null. Eso podría ser porque no puede instanciar la clase.
Veo que al definir la entidad usaste @Builder en la clase misma. Tal vez sería mejor escribir manualmente los constructores y anotar el de todos los argumentos con @Builder. Esto porque entiendo que esta anotación por defecto vuelve a todos los constructores privados y eso puede ser un problema.
// Uso Data para ser mas sintético, es equivalente a las anotaciones @Getter,
// @Setter, @EqualsAndHashCode, @ToString y @RequiredArgsConstructor
@Data 
@Entity

public class SP_Inventory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Long idpro;
    private Long idstr;
    private String name;
    private String namepro;
    private Long cant;
    private String recived;
    private String detail;
    
    // constructor para usar el patrón builder
    @Builder
    public SP_Inventory(Long id, Long idpro, Long idstr, String name, String 
         namepro, Long cant, String recived, String detail){
         this.id = id;
         this.idpro = idpro;
         this.idstr = idstr;
         this.name = name;
         this.namepro = namepro;
         this.cant = cant;
         this.recived = recived;
         this.detail = detail;
    }
    // constructor para que spring data jpa genere instancias
    public SP_Inventory(){
    }
}

Si bien es menos agradable crear entidades así, es lo que yo hago para no tener errores en tiempo de ejecución.
